# ResourceClosedException

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting this "org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: This TransactionCoordinator has been closed" when I try to connect multiple Android devices to the webserver.
I get exception in this following code

```
public static List<Ride> getRides(){

session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Ride> rides=session.createCriteria(Ride.class).list(); //Excpetion
session.getTransaction().commit();
return rides;
}
```

Can anyone provide me with any help

Comment: Where do you declare the `session` variable? Keep thread-safety in mind...

Comment: I have implemented HibernateUtil class for that which is loaded on server startup and SessionFactory is made

Comment: Again, where do you declare the `session` variable (show the class containing `getRides`? As the `getRides` method is static I bet the issue occurs after connecting more than one client.

Comment: I have declared session variable in the same class where getRides() is defined and it is static

Comment: And issue do occur when I connect more than two client

Comment: So you probably have a concurrency issue, just think about what's going to happen to `session` if 2 or more clients access the system concurrently...

Comment: I got your point. Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate Session is not thread-safe. In an webserver environment it must not be used in a static method neither there must be a static variable. (Webserver accesses are treated in different threads.)